# Error when checking target: expected output to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement Inception model on Google colab and when I run `model.fit`, I got this error. Anybody can help me?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-b030aa96e908> in <module>()
      4                     batch_size=256,
      5                     epochs=epochs,
----> 6                     callbacks=[lr_sc])

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    139                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    140                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 141                             str(data_shape))
    142     return data
    143 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected output to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

My code here:

```
epochs = 25
initial_lrate = 0.001

def decay(epoch, steps=100):
    initial_lrate = 0.001
    drop = 0.96
    epochs_drop = 8
    lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop, math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
    return lrate

sgd = SGD(lr=initial_lrate, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)

lr_sc = LearningRateScheduler(decay, verbose=1)

model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy'], loss_weights=[1, 0.3, 0.3], optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And model.fit here:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, 
                    [y_train, y_train, y_train], 
                    validation_data=(X_test, [y_test, y_test, y_test]), 
                    batch_size=256, 
                    epochs=epochs, 
                    callbacks=[lr_sc])
```

Comment: Anybody here? Help me

Comment: can you share the full visibility of your code?

Comment: I Implement by this tutor:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/understanding-inception-network-from-scratch/